How to securly display a file in gcs bucket on web
I have a couple of PDF and img files in a GCS bucket. Each of those files belongs to separate users. I have identifiers that point the files to specific users. What is the secure way of displaying the files in the bucket to the users on a website? The first option is to make the GCS bucket files accessible publicly and display them to the users via the public URL but this is a bad idea cause anyone can access anyone's file. How do sites like Google Drive achieve this? Any explanation is appreciated.

In that case, you have 2 solutions that require you can match the current authenticated user with their own files:

you can directly serve the file from your website, but if the file are large it's not the correct solution
the best solution is to generate a signedURL, a limited in time access to the file with a specific URL.

In both solution, the user can't save the link, it will have to go back to the website and authenticate again.

You can consider using Firebase Security Rules for Cloud Storage which is tied in to Firebase Authentication for user based security. When a user is authenticated with Firebase Authentication, you will know who they are, Cloud Storage lets you specify per file and per path authorization rules that live on servers and determine access to the files in your app.
Here is sample storage rules for User private files:
match /users/{userId}/profilePicture.png {
  allow read;
  allow write: if request.auth.uid == userId;
}

If you want to control who can access your google cloud storage buckets and objects with what permissions using Terraform, check this tutorial

but doesn't every user have to authenticate with firebase/google oauth in this case?

Yes, it it will give access to user based on authentication. Or you can make certain files public based on your requirement.

I can't use Google oauth . We use custom authentication. I can do the public method you suggested without Firebase directly on gcs bucket permissions too, but I can't do that because of the problem I mentioned in my question above.

You can check this document for Additional access control options.
